# Anyone know whats the error in following C code

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
main()
{
    typedef struct
    {
        int info;
        struct strc* next_ptr;
    }strc;
    strc* strcVar[5];
    strcVar = malloc(sizeof(strc) * 5);
    strcVar[0]->info = 1;
    printf(" All is well ");
}
```

Comment: And what compiler says? Or how do you know there is an error?

Comment: You should learn about the difference between structures and pointers to structures.

Answer (score 2):

`strcVar` is a (local) array name, you can't assign a pointer to it. You probably wanted:

```
 strc* strcVar;
 ... /* and  later */
 strcVar[0].info = 1;
```

Maybe you wanted an array of pointers to `struct strc`, then the answer by Vaughn Cato will help.

Answer (score 2):

This line is wrong and unnecessary:

```
strcVar = malloc(sizeof(strc) * 5);
```

instead you might use:

```
{
  int i=0;
  for (;i!=5; ++i) {
    strcVar[i] = malloc(sizeof(strc));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign an array from `malloc` - it's one or the other. If you declared an array of five pointers, the memory for them is allocated already. If you must use `malloc`, use a pointer to pointer instead of an array. Otherwise, allocate the individual items with `malloc`, not the array:

```
strc* strcVar[5];
strcVar[0] = malloc(sizeof(strc));
```

Comment: Sorry the `#include` typo was my mistake when editing his code

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
 strc* strcVar[5];
```

to

```
 strc* strcVar;
 strcVar = malloc(sizeof(strc) * 5);
 strcVar[0].info = 1;
```

**OR**

Change

```
strc* strcVar[5];
strcVar = malloc(sizeof(strc) * 5);
strcVar[0]->info = 1;
```

to

```
strc strcVar[5];
strcVar[0].info = 1;
```

Comment: Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer leads to UB and will most likely crash, you don't want to give the first piece of advice to OP.

Comment: @H2CO3 - Oops - being a bit too handy with the delete key!

Answer (score 1):

**fix code:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main()
{
    typedef struct
    {
        int info;
        struct strc* next_ptr;
    }strc;
    strc* strcVar;
    strcVar = malloc(sizeof(strc) * 5);
    strcVar[0].info = 1;
    printf(" All is well ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In any array the base address is a const pointer. You cannot change it.

Suppose if you have int a[5];

Here a is the base pointer to the whole array and you are not allowed to change it.

This applies to all the arrays.